# how to import Laravel 4.2 live project into locallhost

Tags: laravel, web-applications, import, laravel-4, localhost

i am importing a live Laravel 4.2 Web application and setup it into my localhost for development.
in the Laravel 5 we usually find the .env file in the root dictionary but in Laravel 4.2 i couldn't be able to find .env and another component and their dictionaries are also different.
can anybody tell me how to import my laravel 4.2 web app into the local host step by step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the configuration files for the Laravel framework are stored in the app/config directory [1](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration). You have to set everything directly there or build an own  .env.local.php file with default values like this:

```php
<?php
//file: /.env.local.php
// return the configuration for the 'local' environment
return array(
    'db_host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'db_name' => 'DB_NAME', // specify database name 
    'db_user' => 'DB_USER', // specify database username 
    'db_pass' => 'DB_PASS', // specify database password
);
```

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmad what isn't helpful, *bro* ?

Comment: I am new to the framwork, I need step by step can you do it bro?